# Eliminate duplicate records in rail where condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to fetch a record which has unique value .Below is the output which i am getting now after Using

```
VoucherNumber.where(:goodie=> 2917)
[#<VoucherNumber id: 559, vendor_id: 5, voucher_number: "1", trip_id: nil, expiry_date: "2016-03-23 18:30:00", goodie_id: 2917, status: "UN", amount: #<BigDecimal:8f9b7f0,'0.122E3',9(36)>, created_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22", updated_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22">, #<VoucherNumber id: 565, vendor_id: 5, voucher_number: "4", trip_id: nil, expiry_date: "2016-03-23 18:30:00", goodie_id: 2917, status: "UN", amount: #<BigDecimal:8faf750,'0.122E3',9(36)>, created_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22", updated_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22">, #<VoucherNumber id: 567, vendor_id: 11, voucher_number: "sss", trip_id: nil, expiry_date: "2016-03-22 18:30:00", goodie_id: 2917, status: "UN", amount: #<BigDecimal:8fad7c0,'0.112E3',9(36)>, created_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22", updated_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22">, #<VoucherNumber id: 569, vendor_id: 11, voucher_number: "22", trip_id: nil, expiry_date: "2016-03-22 18:30:00", goodie_id: 2917, status: "UN", amount: #<BigDecimal:902d510,'0.112E3',9(36)>, created_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22", updated_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22">]..



But expected output is below output
[#<VoucherNumber id: 559, vendor_id: 5, voucher_number: "1", trip_id: nil, expiry_date: "2016-03-23 18:30:00", goodie_id: 2917, status: "UN", amount: #<BigDecimal:8f9b7f0,'0.122E3',9(36)>, created_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22", updated_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22"> #<VoucherNumber id: 567, vendor_id: 11, voucher_number: "sss", trip_id: nil, expiry_date: "2016-03-22 18:30:00", goodie_id: 2917, status: "UN", amount: #<BigDecimal:8fad7c0,'0.112E3',9(36)>, created_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22", updated_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22">]
```

Can some one point me in right direction?

Comment: VoucherNumber.where(:goodie=> 2917)--->this is the query i wrote...

Comment: In my case goodie_id and vendor_id shud be unique...I need to find goodie_id and then keep unique records of vendor_id

Comment: Expected output:   [#<VoucherNumber id: 559, vendor_id: 5, voucher_number: "1", trip_id: nil, expiry_date: "2016-03-23 18:30:00", goodie_id: 2917, status: "UN", amount: #<BigDecimal:8f9b7f0,'0.122E3',9(36)>, created_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22", updated_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22"> #<VoucherNumber id: 567, vendor_id: 11, voucher_number: "sss", trip_id: nil, expiry_date: "2016-03-22 18:30:00", goodie_id: 2917, status: "UN", amount: #<BigDecimal:8fad7c0,'0.112E3',9(36)>, created_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22", updated_at: "2016-03-04 11:37:22">]

Comment: Hey you can use `VoucherNumber.group('goodie, vendor_id')`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `uniq` method, that ensures you don't get the same record twice.

```
VoucherNumber.where(:goodie=> 2917).uniq
```

## Edit:

```
VoucherNumber.where(:goodie => 2917).pluck(:vendor_id).uniq
```

Comment: But i need to find first goodie id with 2917 and then filter unique records of vendor_id

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way but it returns only `vendor_id`

```
VoucherNumber.where(:goodie=> 2917).uniq.pluck(:vendor_id)
```

You can find all columns using for all goodie with `goodie` and `vendor_id` uniq

```
VoucherNumber.group("goodie,vendor_id")
```

For selected goodie as:

```
VoucherNumber.where(:goodie=> 2917).group(:vendor_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
VoucherNumber.where(:goodie=> 2917).group('goodie, vendor_id')
```

Answer (score -1):

try `group_by vendor_id` and then `uniq` on that result.

```
VoucherNumber.where(:goodie=> 2917).select("DISTINCT(vendor)")
```

the query is,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(vendor) FROM "voucher_numbers" WHERE "voucher_numbers"."goodie" = 2917
```

Comment: yes, exclduing uniq will also work for the group by.

Comment: Updated the ans please check

Comment: @Sravan you are grouping using `id` what is meaning of it?? it return all records because `id` is `uniq` for all

Comment: I updated my ans, remove grouping by id, and added distinct, please check now.